# war file Deployment problem in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss

If I have a war file genarated in Windows machine and I deploy that to the Jboss in Linux environment, Do I need to make any changes in Jboss server configuration files?

When I tried to open an application it says the "The requested resource (/helloworld) is not available". But the same application if I open in Windows Environment it works really great.

I tried restarting the server as well, but no Help.

For the first time I have installed the JBoss in my Virtual Private Server, 
http://:8080/, I get the Jboss Home Page, when I click on jmx_console, that page is also coming without any problem. this is to make sure Jboss is working fine or not.

Please help if I am missing some thing in this?

Comment: Have you deployed *other* WARs to the Linux instance, i.e. are you sure that JBoss itself is working correctly on the Linux box?

Comment: Which version of JBoss are you using?

Comment: This is the first war File I have deployed in Linux instance. I am using the jboss 5

Answer (score 0):

> war file genarated in Windows machine
>   and I deploy that to the Jboss in
>   Linux environment, Do I need to make
>   any changes in Jboss server
>   configuration files?

No.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a trap between windows and linux. (I don't have a Linux-Box so I can't test it).

The Linux-Box may be case-sensitive.

Within the JMX-Console you can search for your deployed Web-App and the deplyment-path. May be the path is: `http://jbosshost:8080/HelloWorld`

Take a look at the JMX-Xonsole:
http://jbosshost:8080/jmx-console/ (Filter for: *jboss.web.deployment*)